# Asus Windows Vista Home Premium product key expired

Tags: windows-vista, product-key

I can't start my laptop in normal mode. It says that my product key is already expired and I need to type a new one. I have a product key on the back of my laptop, but it seems to be not valid. If I start it in safe mode it starts, but almost all of the programs are not functioning, and even when I insert a flash drive it won't work.

The recovery DVD doesn't work either.

Can you tell me how to repair it?

Comment: run this tool, copy and post the output here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012

Answer (score 0):

my experience on this topic is, that the easiest way to handle this problem, is to contact microsoft, explain the details, and they can guide you the correct way.

because, the key you have only fits a specific version of vista ( language specific and such does also count)

tryed it once before. back then, as i remember my key godt lost in one of their machine upgrades.

Best of luck.